# Access SQL Update with Exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need some direction with an Access update query.  I have two tables 1)Rebates & 2)DCN.  I want to join these tables on the field DCN where the Rebates table is "Not Mapped".  Easy enough but I want to only update Rebates where the join returns a value otherwise not mapped is replaced with a null. I am reviewed 40 or so sites with different components of the query but I cannot seem to put it all together.  I believe I need to alias the Rebates table and just can't come up with the correct syntax. Below is the general idea and this produces a syntax error when the "And Exists.." is added.
Thanks for taking a look.

```
UPDATE REBATES 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_DCN As A ON REBATES.[Distributor Customer]=A.DISTRIBUTOR_CUSTOMER_ID 
SET REBATES.ID = A.[Customer_ID]
WHERE (((REBATES.ID)="Not Mapped"))
And Exists (LEFT JOIN Tbl_DCN As b ON REBATES.[Distributor Customer]=b.DISTRIBUTOR_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

Comment: REBATES.ID what is the field type, Number or String, if number it can be null or it is 0?

Answer (score 1):

The code below will update REBATES.ID  the value will be retrieved from Tbl_DCN.Customer_ID where REBATES.ID is missing.

```
UPDATE REBATES INNER JOIN Tbl_DCN ON REBATES.[Distributor Customer] = Tbl_DCN.DISTRIBUTOR_CUSTOMER_ID SET REBATES.ID = [Tbl_DCN].[Customer_ID]
WHERE (((REBATES.ID) = "Not Mapped"));
```

Comment: Thanks - I was making this much more complicated than it really was.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE REBATES 
LEFT JOIN Tbl_DCN As A 
ON REBATES.[Distributor Customer]=A.DISTRIBUTOR_CUSTOMER_ID 
SET REBATES.ID = A.[Customer_ID]
WHERE (((REBATES.ID)="Not Mapped"))
And Exists 
(select 1 from REBATES LEFT JOIN Tbl_DCN As b 
 ON REBATES.[DistributorCustomer]=b.DISTRIBUTOR_CUSTOMER_ID);
```

You can try this.